# When will the Stack Overflow API be released?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, api

When will the Stack Overflow API be released and what should the community expect from it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The public API covers this request, and is available now:

- https://stackapps.com/

Use the API to build a mobile app or site to your taste!

Answer (score 2):

Now that there's a [new member on the team](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/welcome-stack-overflow-valued-associate-000004/) (that will be focused on the API), I expect it will be in about 6 to 8 weeks