# Browser plugin for SO feeds. Can it be really useful?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

Just an idea that a browser plugin displaying recent related activity for a user can be really useful rather than opening the SO site and navigating around or browsing through emails. I personally like echofon for twitter, I feel that something similar for SO can be a timesaver for many regulars here.

Answer (score 3):

We're still waiting for an [official API](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/when-will-the-stack-overflow-api-be-released) with which browser plugins can be made.

But till then, you can [help yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemonkey-implementations) a lot with [what has already been made using Greasemonkey](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/greasemonkey).

Also, what [@sockpuppet said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34675/browser-plugin-for-so-feeds-can-it-be-really-useful/34677#34677).

Comment: I heard from a very reliable source that the API will be released in 6-8 weeks.

Comment: @sockpuppet: yeah, that's what I heard as well...

Comment: Sounds real cool

Answer (score 3):

We all want browser extensions, iPhone and Android apps, notifiers and whatnot. Until there's an official API, as [fretje](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34675/browser-plugin-for-so-feeds-can-it-be-really-useful/34676#34676) pointed out, none of these are really possible (they are, but they're not exactly what most of us want).

Your best bet right now is to simply use RSS feeds. It's an imperfect solution to a lingering problem.

Comment: I'm not upvoting sockpuppet accounts! Hey, wait, I did...

Comment: It's **your** sockpuppet account, man. If you don't agree with yourself, who else can you agree with?

Comment: Do you really try to argue with the hand which let you speak? The Hand of God?

Comment: Sorry, master! I was trying to make it look like I'm not really a sockpuppet. Damn these multiple personalities!