# Polite HTML Scraping possible?

Tags: discussion, api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Etiquette of Screen-scraping Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/etiquette-of-screen-scraping-stack-overflow)

Considering that [there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12224/what-would-you-want-to-see-in-a-stackoverflow-api) [isn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35723/what-do-you-want-to-build-with-the-so-api) [yet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/when-will-the-stack-overflow-api-be-released) [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/when-will-the-stack-overflow-api-be-released) [defined](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36023/api-for-accessing-stackoverflow-closed) [api](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34952/how-is-there-no-stackoverflow-api-yet) [or](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35743/what-is-the-intended-purpose-of-the-stackoverflow-api-closed) [even](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17037/unofficial-stack-overflow-api-reference) [a](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35966/desired-so-f-u-api-feedback) [release](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16827/does-stackoverflow-provide-a-public-api-for-querying) date for it, I've resorted to using some cURL requests to scrape content off of the various {M}S[O,U,F] sites.

I'm currently setting a unique `USERAGENT`

> curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "[M]S[OUF] - http://codebase.unchartedmess.com");

and not doing any heavy scraping. Mostly it's just the front page looking for updates and tagged questions, but it could end up actively crawling the sites.

Is there a polite way to do this?

Comment: Have you taken a look at the data dump?

Comment: I'm not particularly worried about past data as I am about current data. Right now I'm working on a local project that will scroll current activity from the various trilogy sites all on one page.